# What parameters matter when selecting a replacement stepper motor?

Tags: motor, encoder

The stepper motor (most likely, the encoder) on a legacy system is not reporting the position, and I am considering to find a drop-in replacement with similar specs, size (NEMA 23), and number of steps on the encoder.

My goal is to find a motor that is similar enough to avoid tuning.

**What parameters should I try to match when choosing a new stepper to minimize the amount of tuning that needs to be done?**

Below are the specs for

the malfunctioning device:

```
Model #                         5718M-05P (Lin Engineering)
Rated Current (Amps/Phase)      2.80
Holding Torque (N-m)            1.22
Resistance (Ohms/Phase)         0.9
Inductance (mH/Phase)           2.5
Inertia (oz-in²)                1.5
Weight (Lbs.)                   1.5 (0.68 kg)
Number of Leads                 4
```

... and the motor replacement candidate:

```
Model #                         QSH5718_10000 (Trinamic)
Rated Current (Amps/Phase)      2.8
Holding Torque (N-m)            1.01
Resistance (Ohms/Phase)         0.83
Inductance (mH/Phase)           2.2
Inertia (oz-in²)                275 g/cm2 (?)
Weight (Lbs.)                   1.5
Number of Leads                 4
```

Would I achieve my goal with the candidate part above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion from oz.in<sup>2</sup> to gm.cm<sup>2</sup> is x 28.35(gm/oz) x 2.54<sup>2</sup>(cm/in)  = 183 times. This gives 274 for your existing motor.

Most parameters appear to be within spitting distance of each other. They are clearly almost the same.

The lower inductance, resistance and torque suggests the replacement has a lower torque constant, so with the same inertia may have slightly lower acceleration than the one you're replacing.

The lower resistance means less heat when current driving. Lower inductance means quicker torque response if voltage driving, which may offset the lower acceleration. You would also require less over voltage if current driving.

If you have a very demanding application where tuning is critical, then you will already be current driving, as it's faster than voltage driving. You may need to retune. If not, it looks like you can just drop it in.